# pointers in argument, ampersand?

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing, ampersand

I pass a pointer to a function, I can access struct's members from the pointer.

In this function I need to call another function with the same pointer as argument.
I use the ampersand but application stopped.

How to call anotherfunction() from myfunction() ?

```
bool anotherfunction( const ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms * parms )
{
    myStruct info;
    info.layout = parms->program->parmLayout.pipelineLayout; // application error
}

bool myfunction( const ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms * parms )
{
    myStruct info;
    info.layout = parms->program->parmLayout.pipelineLayout; // Works

    anotherfunction( &parms ); // compile, but application stopped
}

void main()
{
    myfunction( &pipelineParms );
}
```

Comment: Don't apply `&`. `parms` is already a pointer and should just be passed on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, the `&` character before a variable does not mean "this thing is a pointer".  No, when you put `&` before a variable, it means "make me a pointer to this".

So when you called

```
myfunction(&pipelineParms);
```

you had a variable `pipelineParms`, and you created a pointer to it, and it was that pointer you passed to `myfunction`.

Then, in `myfunction`, `parms` was a pointer (specifically, a pointer to type `ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms`.  Hopefully, `pipelineParms` in `main` was type `ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms` also.)

So in `myfunction`, if you want to pass the pointer on to `anotherfunction`, just pass it:

```
anotherfunction(parms);
```

We can see that `anotherfunction` also accepts a pointer to type `ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms`, so this is correct.

When you tried to call `anotherfunction(&parms)`, the `&` said, "make me a pointer to this".  So you got a pointer to *a pointer to* type `ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms`, or `ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms **`.  That might be fine if that's what `anotherfunction` expects, but it's not.

It's not that C has regular variables, and pointers to regular variables.  You can have pointers to *anything*.  You can have pointers to pointers, and pointers to pointers to pointers, and theoretically you can have 4- and 5- and 6-level pointers, too, all the way up to 12 or more (although in practice anything beyond 3 is extremely rare).

One more thing: You said

```
anotherfunction( &parms ); // compile, but application stopped
```

but I'm guessing it did not, in fact, compile properly.  I'm guessing your compiler gave you a warning.  Mine says:

> warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'const ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms **' to parameter of type 'const ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms *'; remove &

If your compiler didn't give you a warning on that line, I encourage you to switch to a better compiler, if at all possible.  (A modern compiler would also warn you about `void main`, which is also wrong, although it's not causing you any problems.)

Answer (score 1):

```
anotherfunction( &parms ); // compile, but application stopped
```

You already have `parms` as pointer, you don't need `&`.

```
anotherfunction( parms ); // compile, but application stopped
```

If you append `&` to `parms` it will become `onst ovrVkGraphicsPipelineParms **`

Comment: instead of "you don't need `&`" I would write "using `&` is wrong"

Comment: I accept the other answer which was more complete, but thank you.

Comment: @GUNNM The answer by SteveSummit deserves it :).